# How can I set up a macro using TikZ to draw "identify braces"?

Tags: tikz-pgf

An identify brace on a graph tells the reader that the two points "identified" are topologically equivalent. That is, the correct way to understand the graph is to cut it out, roll it into a cylinder, and glue it together at the points being identified. Here's an MS Paint example:

[image]

How can I make a TikZ macro for such identify braces? One would typically need horizontal and vertical braces, in both "equals sign up", "equals sign down" (horizontal) or "equals sign left", "equals sign right" (vertical) flavours.

Comment: Can you atleast draw the lines for a MWE? I mean, come on. You have 6 gazillion points, you should know better

Comment: Is it a brace, like `{` but under the segment?

Comment: Whats wrong with \underbrace{\rule{\width}{0pt}}?

Comment: So you want a horizontal brace, with the tip replaced by a vertical equal sign?

Comment: @KevinC That's right.

Comment: @Sigur See KevinC's comment.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It's not easy to set up the start/end point of that relative to the TikZ grid?

Comment: @percusse I have some idea of how to start it off, but I am scared of getting started because this is just fancy stuff that I'll use if I can (otherwise, I can just print out the stuff and draw in the identification braces by hand), since I have a midterm on Friday I really ought to be spending more time on :( -- once I get TeXing, *hours* go bye (pun intended)....

Comment: @user89: "I have some idea of how to start it off, but I am scared of getting started..." Sorry, but that just isn't good enough!

Comment: @user89 We are talking about 7 lines of stupid code for a starting MWE please let's not discuss. This is not college admission. It's just a question.

Answer (score 3):

You can start with this. A command `\myequivdown` which draws something similar to what you want between to nodes. It's easy to replicate for equals going up, right or left.
Change command name, angles and distances to your taste.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\myequivdown}[2]{
    \path (#1.south)--coordinate[midway] (aux) (#2.south);
    \draw (#1.south) to [out=-89,in=181] ([shift={(-.5mm,-3mm)}]aux)--++(-90:3mm);
    \draw (#2.south) to [out=-91,in=-1] ([shift={(.5mm,-3mm)}]aux)--++(-90:3mm);
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)--(4,0);
    \draw (0.5,.3)--(0.5,-.3) node[below] (zero) {\strut 0};
    \draw (3.5,.3)--(3.5,-.3) node[below] (two) {\strut 2 pi};
    \myequivdown{zero}{two}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]